# Inserting variable between text in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, innerhtml

What is wrong with my syntax if I wish for this onClick function to produce the  tag with the proper filename (ie "img/18.png")? Chromium console reports no errors and no HTML is produced.

I'm using a library known as seedrandom.min.js to seed the random generator.

```js
    function newCard() {
const randGeneratorFrom = seed => {
  const generator = new Math.seedrandom(seed)
  return (min, max) => Math.floor(generator() * max) + min
}

const now = new Date();
const seed = [now.getHours(), now.getMilliseconds(), now.getMinutes(), now.getSeconds(), now.getMilliseconds(), now.getDay()].join(':')
const rand = randGeneratorFrom(seed)

console.info(seed)
var firstCard = rand(1, 78);
document.getElementById("card1").innerHTML = "<img src='img/", firstCard, ".png>";
}
```

```html
    <button onclick="newCard()">Click me</button>
    <div id="card1"></div>
```

Comment: Use `+` instead of comma to concatenate a variable in a string.... `= "<img src='img/" + firstCard + ".png>";`

Comment: You should (almost) never use innerHTML. It is an unsafe way of constructing HTML in JavaScript.

Answer (score 5):

This is not how string concatenation works in javascript:

```js
"<img src='img/", firstCard, ".png>"
```

You can either use the `+` operator:

```js
"<img src='img/" + firstCard + ".png'>"
```

Or use a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (note the backticks):

```js
`<img src='img/${firstCard}.png'>"`
```

---

Note: Your code is also missing the closing `'` after `.png`.

Comment: You are my hero of the week. I devote prayer candle to you if you are receptive. Have a good day